# Mouseleave event unexpectedly fired or triggered when div element is being animated (jQuery or CSS transition) in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, animation, mouseleave

I have a drop-down-menu with a height-animated content inside. Sometimes, during any random animation cycle, a mouseleave-even gets fired in Google Chrome (v69, Windows 10).

See the fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xgf2qrLj/)

```js
$('#menu li').hover(
 function(event) {
   $(this).find('.box').show();
  },
  function(event) {
  // current workaround
  if(event.target === $(this).find('.more-link')[0]){
     console.log('Doing a return here would be a workaround but not the bugfix.');
      // return;
    }
   $(this).find('.box').hide();
  }
);

$('.more-link')
 .unbind('click.more')
 .bind('click.more', function() {
    $moreLink = $(this);
   $more = $moreLink.parent().find('.more');

    if ($more.is(':visible')) {
     $moreLink.text('more...');
      $more.hide('blind', {}, 250);
    } else {
     $moreLink.text('less...');
    $more.show('blind', {}, 250);
    }
  });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  background-color: #efefef;
  border-right: 1px solid #cccccc;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: tomato;
}

div.box {
  background-color: orange;
  border: 2px solid tomato;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 76px;
  left: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
}

div.content {
  padding: 5px;
}

div.more {
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

a.more-link {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <a>Link 1</a>
    <div class="box">
      <a class="more-link">more...</a>
      <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      <div class="more">More content 1.</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Link 2</a>
    <div class="box">
      <a class="more-link">more...</a>
      <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      <div class="more">More content 2.</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Link 3</a>
    <div class="box">
      <a class="more-link">more...</a>
      <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      <div class="more">More content 3.</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. hover on any li element
2. click on "more..." or "less..."
3. repeat step 2 in quick succession
4. after a random number of clicks, the mouseleave event fires and the box disappears

Following things I have found out so far:

- The quicker the animation, the less often the problem occurs
- The problem occurs both with jQuery animate approach and CSS transition approach
- without animation, it does not occur
- CSS translate3d and backface-visibility fixes do not work for me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have been trying to reproduce this issue with no avail. I'm using Chrome v69 and Windows 10. Could it be something related to the last chrome version you where using? Because recently google chrome changed it's layout.